# Glusterfs Peer Replication

Tags: drupal, glusterfs

I'm planning to implement glusterfs cluster with nodes (Drupal servers) with out client. I'm experiencing replication problem with in the peer.

Does nodes in glusterfs cluster replicate data each other or should we compulsory need gluster  clients? Usually my files will be images and some flv's. Please suggest me any other tool which is similar to Glusterfs.

Thanks,

Swaroop.

Comment: You need to use glusterfs client for proper replication and fail over to function properly across the nodes. Its not recommended to use mix gluster and nfs clients.

Comment: you have duplicated question with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305054/glusterfs-not-replicating-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can replicate the nodes each other by installing the client in the same node. Following links are helpful for you :

```
http://gopukrish.wordpress.com/glusterfs/
http://gopukrish.wordpress.com/high-availability-load-balanced-wordpress-site/
```